# How to load another UI when screen rotate?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-orientation

I used Navigation Controller to load fragments. I need to load two fragments on the same screen when the user rotates the screen. I do not have an idea how can I achieve this.
Can somebody help me with this? I added some code which I tried.

```
override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment, FirstFragment())
                .commitAllowingStateLoss()
        }else{
            val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
            appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
            setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        }
    }
```

This is portrait UI
[image]

This is landscape UI I wanted to achieve this
[image]

After switching to landscape to portrait its look like this
[image: .]

Comment: Would overriding layout on `layout-land` help?